# NoMethodError in SabisuRails::ExplorerController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been following the api on rails tutorial and have installed the sabisu gem as was described in the tutorial and i have also checked out the documentation on github. When i try and open the page in my browser with rails server running i get the above error. Alongside this i get the following error.

undefined method `singularize' for :users:Symbol

I am not too sure why this is happening. The code for my config file for sabisu is below but i have checked that all this is as it should be.

```
# Use this module to configure the sabisu available options

SabisuRails.setup do |config|

  # Base uri for posting the 
  config.base_api_uri = 'api.marketplaceapi.dev'

  # Ignored attributes for building the forms
  # config.ignored_attributes = %w{ created_at updated_at id }

  # HTTP methods
  # config.http_methods = %w{ GET POST PUT DELETE PATCH }

  # Headers to include on each request
  #
  # You can configure the api headers fairly easy by just adding the correct headers
  config.api_headers = { "Accept" => "application/vnd.marketplace.v1" }
  #
  # config.api_headers = {}

  # Layout configuration
  # config.layout = "sabisu"

  # Resources on the api
  config.resources = [:users]

  # Default resource
  config.default_resource = :users

  # Application name
  # mattr_accessor :app_name
  # @@app_name = Rails.application.class.parent_name

  # Authentication
  # mattr_accessor :authentication_username
  # @@authentication_username = "admin"

  # mattr_accessor :authentication_password
  # @@authentication_password = "sekret"

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug SabisuRails.  You can get around it by using a string instead of a symbol when setting the default_resource:

```
config.default_resource = 'users'
```